# Ant Design - Currency Input with comma decimal separator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, antd

I want to use Antd's `<InputNumber />` component as monetary input, and I'm using like official documentation suggests:

```
<InputNumber
    min={0}
    size="large"
    style={{ width: 400 }}
    formatter={value => `$ ${value}`.replace(new RegExp(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g), ',')}
    parser={value => value.replace(new RegExp(/\$\s?|(,*)/g), '')}
/>
```

But I wish I could using comma digit like a decimal separator: `R$ 17.350,70`

What is the correct regex format and parser for input my currency information?

Comment: Do you mean that `123456789` should be converted to  `1.234.567,89`?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want!

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros I'm with the same issue.. you managed to fix it ?

Comment: @GiuliaLage Still looking for workarounds

Comment: I answered the question but some guy deleted, I just wanted to help with a alternative solution using Input instead of input Number and some dependencies... if wanna take a look again  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430864/regex-inputnumber-formatter-ant-design

Answer (score 2):

This would be more concise if JavaScript `RegExp` had a backwards flag.  Since it doesn't, we have to reverse the string, insert the punctuation, then reverse it back.

Parsing is simply replacing all non-numbers, `\D`, with nothing.

I am more familiar with using the period `.` as a decimal, and commas `,` as thousands separators, but it should be easy for you to invert this.

```js
const numbers = [1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567, 12345678, 123456789].map(String);

function format(number) {
  return number
    .split('').reverse().join('')
    .replace(/(\d{1,2})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,3})?/, '$1.$2,$3,$4')
    .split('').reverse().join('')
    .replace(/^,+/, '')
}

function parse(money) {
  return money.replace(/\D/g, '');
}

function log(n) {
  console.log(n);
}

numbers
  .map(format)
  .forEach(log);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already late for the main questioner, but since it took me quite a considerable amount of time to figure it out so I want to provide my formatter-function in case someone is still looking for a clean solution to format input numbers to currency (with thousand separators and two digits decimal places)

```
const formatNumberWithThousandSeparatorAndTwoDecimalPlaces = value => new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
}).format(value).replace(/€/g, '');
```

called like:

```
 formatter={formatNumberWithThousandSeparatorAndTwoDecimalPlaces}
```

the above function turns a 123456 to 123.456,00 and a 123456.78 to
123.456,78
You also need to set the following property

```
 decimalSeparator = {','}
```

*Feel free to change the decimal separator or the locale/Currency type!
*You need also a parser if you want to parse the input to a desired formatted number: something like:

```
 parser={value => value.replace('.', '').replace(/,/g, '.')}
```

so you have a 123456.78 from a 123.456,78.

*You can leave the `.format(value).replace(/€/g, '')` part if you want to keep the currency symbol but later you have to add this to the parser function